# Not receiving data with C# serial port class (4800bps, Even parity, 2 stopbits, 7 databits)

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have to communicate with a MarCator digital Indicator via serial (I usb a serial to USB adaptor).
The protocol is:
DTR to -Vdd for 100ms to 1s.
Then the frame of 9 bytes is emitted 15ms to 160ms later.

With TeraTerm, it works like a charm but I'm not able to make it work with C#.

```
Char[] buff = new Char[9];
SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM25", 4800, Parity.Even, 7, StopBits.Two);

Console.WriteLine("Created");
port.Open();
port.DtrEnable = true;
Console.WriteLine("Open");
Thread.Sleep(500);

port.DtrEnable = false;
Thread.Sleep(500);
port.DtrEnable = true;

Thread.Sleep(200);
if (port.BytesToRead != 0) {
    port.Read(buff, 0, 9);
    Console.WriteLine(buff);
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("Fail...");
}
port.Close();
```

I see that the MarCator is receiving the DTR command but port.BytesToRead is always 0.

Regards,
Val'

Comment: Please describe in detail what it is doing exactly.  Why are you putting the thread to sleep?

Comment: I am putting the thread to sleep to wait the delays imposed by the serial device: Wait 500ms to let it settle. Wait 500ms to respect the 100ms to 1000ms pulse width. Wait 200ms to give the device enough time to answer (15ms to 160ms).

Comment: You forgot to turn on RtsEnable.  Contact the manufacturer for support if that doesn't help.

Comment: Thank you ! With port.RtsEnable = true, it works. What is the purpose of this property ?